# IOS 13 push notifications stopped coming

Tags: python, objective-c, react-native, push-notification

We have a react-native App which has an sdk for push notifications and analytics. After the update of IOS 13 i had to change my code for registration of notifications like this

```
- (void)didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    WLLOG(@"DEVICE TOKEN: %@", deviceToken);

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"13.0")) {
      self.deviceToken = [[[deviceToken.description stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""]
                           stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
                          stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    } else {
      NSUInteger dataLength = deviceToken.length;

      const unsigned char *dataBuffer = (const unsigned char *)deviceToken.bytes;
      NSMutableString *hexString  = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:(dataLength * 2)];
      for (NSInteger index = 0; index < dataLength; ++index) {
        [hexString appendFormat:@"%02x", dataBuffer[index]];
      }
      self.deviceToken = [hexString copy];
    }

    [self sendDeviceInfoIfNecessary];
}
```

I actually added the else part. The notifications mechanism was working until the past two or three days that I noticed that the problem came back again and I can't receive push notifications at devices with IOS 13.

In back end we use python 2 and the libraries apns-client(0.2.1) ,apns2(0.7.1) which are responsible for sending the request to APNS. Apple's response has no errors.

Does anyone know if there is another update I should add to my code?

Also is there any tool for sending push notifications that has all the updates and is proved that is working with IOS 13?

Answer (score 0):

As iOS 13 brought security and privacy update.So it does't allow to get push notifications with existing oneSignal package.That needs to be updated manually.So you can follow these simple steps to update node_modules of your app for onesignal. It will work then for all versions of iOS

[Manually update oneSignal SDK for iOS 13+](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup#section-manually-updating-i-os-one-signal-native-sdk)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but we have our own sdk we don't use oneSignal

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I hadn't update my xcode and did not have supporting files for ios 13.3